# Cannot connect to MySQL in Docker from .NET app (in docker)

Tags: mysql, .net, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, yaml

I have a docker stack with a .NET app and a MySQL server.

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Password@1234"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "Password@1234"
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  app:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ../App/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 7040:443
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;
    depends_on:
        - mysql
        - mongo
```

When I try to connect to the server with the following connection string:

`"Server=mysql;User=root;Pwd=Password@1234;Database=db"`

I get an exception like so:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the UseMySq' call.
Inner Exception: MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Quite weird since I can connect to the database from Azure Data Studio.

Can't figure out what's wrong here. Not sure how this is transient, since when I use `DbContext.Database.CanConnect()` it returns false.

Tried using different users in yaml, different values of the con string, adding SSL. Nothing worked.

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Thanks Mark, pasted the code, makes much more sense.

Comment: Wait .. which is it, Mysql .. or Mongo ?  One is Column Mysql Statement driven and the other is Json Objects only ...

Comment: It's related to MySQL, I will use Mongo for serilog, but it's not related to the issue. Just pasted the whole yaml file.

Comment: I see, just wanted to make sure.   If you do a localhost:3306 you get anything?  Can you even ping that? if not .. there is the problem.

Comment: The database is running as I've said in a docker container. I can access it from Azure Data Studio using root and the password I've specified.

Comment: Ah that is right, dang, well i guess ease of accessibiility is the price to pay for lower overhead I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stupid reason for the issue.

When using

`options.UseMySql(ServerVersion.AutoDetect(conString))`

I didn't add the con string as the first property. Now it works with this:

`options.UseMySql(conString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(conString))`

I thought since

`public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseMySql([NotNull] this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, [CanBeNull] string connectionString, [NotNull] ServerVersion serverVersion, [CanBeNull] Action<MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilder> mySqlOptionsAction = null)`

says that the ConString can be null it will somehow understand what the con string is but it was a baseless asumption.